# Notifying Safari Extension Before Download

Tags: javascript, dom-events, safari-extension

I'm working on a Safari extension and I want it to be notified before a download window appears. Since there is no event for download I guess I have to process the response headers, but I was not able to access them either. I was wondering what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is this an extension what will run on /any/ page? Or on specific ones?  If the second, you could add `onclick` event to the download link.

Comment: It's going to run on any page.

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experience tinkering with Safari and Chrome extensions, I believe you need to listen for a page to fire off either (or both) of these events: `beforeLoad` and `beforeNavigate`. Dealing with `beforeLoad` is described very well in the section on [blocking content](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW9), and `beforeNavigate` is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Extensions/Reference/SafariBeforeNavigateEventClassRef/SafariBeforeNavigateEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010860).

With either of those events, you'd need to determine if the URL in question is a download or a normal web file. I suspect you could do a fast check for common download filetypes such as .zip, .mp3, and others, but the only way to be certain might be to perform your own short HTTP request and analyze the response, as you noted in your question.

Caution: There's no API for detecting downloads because extensions have almost no power over the files on a user's computer anyway. This means that downloads should typically be outside the scope of extensions, and the responsibility of platform-native apps instead.